# Optimizing code with chunk or cursor in laravel

Tags: laravel, laravel-5.4, eloquent

I'm having `Company` Model and `Contact` Model defined in my `Laravel 5.4` application, both of them have many to many relationship. So, for example contacts model has:

```
public function company()
{
    return $this
        ->belongsToMany('App\Company', 'company_contact','contact_id', 'company_id')->withTimestamps();
}
```

Now I've a data set where I want to pull all contacts data and there company details so I was using:

```
public function getData()
{
    $contacts = Contact::all();
    foreach($contacts as $contact)
    {
        $getCompany = $contact->company()->withPivot('created_at')->orderBy('pivot_created_at', 'desc')->first();
        $getCompany->contacts = Company::find($getCompany->id)->contacts;
        $contact->company = $getCompany;
        $contact->companies_interested = json_decode($contact->companies_interested);
        $companies = [];
        if($contact->companies_interested)
        {
            foreach($contact->companies_interested as $companiesInterested)
            {
                $getCompany = Company::withTrashed()->find($companiesInterested);
                $companies[] = array(
                    'value' => $getCompany->id,
                    'label' => $getCompany->name
                );
            }
            $contact->companies_interested = json_encode($companies);
        }
    }
    return response()->json([
        'model' => $contacts
    ], 200);
}
```

This works perfectly fine for small data set, but while using large number of data it fails (approx 10,000 fields), I guess `php memory fails` to load when it comes to large data set. I was going through `Laravel` docs to find out the solution and came to know about `chunk()` and `cursor()` methods, Can someone guide me what can be done in this problem or what can be the approach to overcome this.

Thanks

Comment: Are you familar with Chris Fidao's "Laravel Performant" series? He has a video for Database Chuncking in Laravel that explains exactly what you are trying to implement. It's also free. https://serversforhackers.com/laravel-perf/database-chunking

Answer (score 5):

I recommend you to test both methods for some quirkiness of your system.

Chunk:

It will "paginate" your query, this way you use less memory.

- Uses less memory
- It takes longer

`

```
public function getData() {
    Contact::chunk(1000, function ($contacts) {
        foreach ($contacts as $contact) {
            //rest of your code...
        }
    });
}
```

`

Cursor:

You will use PHP Generators to search your query items one by one.

- It takes less time
- Uses more memory

`

```
public function getData() {
    foreach (Contact::cursor() as $contact) {
        //rest of your code...
    }
}
```

`

For a **more detailed explanation** see this answer: [What is the difference between laravel cursor and laravel chunk method?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45464676/what-is-the-difference-between-laravel-cursor-and-laravel-chunk-method)

For performance **testing** see this post: https://translate.google.com/translate?hl=en&sl=auto&tl=en&u=http%3A%2F%2Fqiita.com%2Fryo511%2Fitems%2Febcd1c1b2ad5addc5c9d

Comment: I don't want data in chunks, I want all the data present in my database and running 2 more query each data in foreach loop, so I used `cursor()` but it ain't helping me out.

Comment: The link which you shared, I had already gone through it, as I mentioned in question I've already done background check.

Comment: i come from c#: doesn't cursoring (linq'ing) the list mean that after you are finished with the item in the cursor it is disposed and thus freeing the memory again?

Comment: I donot think cursor is faster than chunk because cursor will take lot of time in roundtrip