# dispatched jobs stays in memory leading to high memory usage

Tags: php, laravel, redis

I'm working on bringing my memory down when using the `cursor()`method when fetching 3M+ records in Laravel 6.x.

I have a artisan command that runs the following code:

```
Product::cursor()->each(function ($product) {
    calculateStats::dispatch($product);
});
```

According to the documentation, it should result in low memory usage, but the memory just keeps crawling up until it hits my 2G limit.

I read it could be because the PDO connection uses a buffered query, so i tried to add this before running the query:

```
\DB::connection()->getPdo()->setAttribute(\PDO::MYSQL_ATTR_USE_BUFFERED_QUERY, false);
```

from here: https://github.com/laravel/framework/issues/14919

This resulted in a lower start memory usage, but the result is still the same. 
I also tried to add it to the `database.php` config file, but same result.

I'm using MySQL 8, if that makes any difference.

I use the `dispatch()` method to distribute it to the workers, as it would take to long to process them one at a time.

Any good suggestions on how to solve the memory issue?

**EDIT**

After som additional debugging i seems like it is the job dispatching that hugs the memory. 
How can the job be released from memory, as it has already been sent to the Redis-queue?

FIY: the setup uses Redis and Horizon.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Optimizing code with chunk or cursor in laravel](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45467100/optimizing-code-with-chunk-or-cursor-in-laravel)

Comment: I'm not sure you can use the `->each()` method on a generator, could you try rewriting to a foreach loop and see if the issue still happens?

Comment: i have tried with the foreach loop aswell, memory-wise is it the same result.

Comment: Regarding the link @BanujanBalendrakumar, when you use the chunk method on really big tables, it has a huge performance hit because the query does offset x, limit y. it takes longer and longer for each "chunk". The first 100k results is not a problem, but when you hit 1M+, the query is really slow.

Comment: I just ran into this today as well. Chunking issues aside, do `for ($i = 0; $i < 100000; $i++) { EmptyJob::dispatch(); }` and you'll also see the memory slowly climb.

Answer (score 5):

In my case, Laravel's `Telescope` plugin was holding onto a reference to the dispatched job, causing a very noticeable memory leak when ran with 10,000+ jobs.

Comment: `Telescope::stopRecording();`

Comment: After debugging a import script for several days, this was indeed the memory leak we were looking for. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Instead, "remember where you left off": http://mysql.rjweb.org/doc.php/pagination

Sorry, I doubt if this can be expressed directly in Laravel; you may have to drop into SQL to do the task.  Consider filing a feature request for Laravel.