# Slow query in laravel

Tags: laravel, eloquent

I have a laravel application but a query needs a lot of time to be executed.

I tried to build a raw query but  with no success.

The query is this one:

```php
$utente = Utente::with('coll')->with('collaboratori')
            ->where('id', '<>', '0')
            ->whereHas('coll', function ($query) use($id_utente, $att_dummy){
                $query->where('collaboratori_id', 'like', $id_utente);})
            ->orderBy('created_at')
            ->get();
```

I also tried to look over the sql query with the queryLog and there are different query that laravel executed:

```sql
select * from `utenti_nuovo` where `id` <> 0 and exists (select * from `collaboratori_utenti` where `utenti_nuovo`.`id` = `collaboratori_utenti`.`id_utente` 
and `collaboratori_id` like 100008) order by `created_at` asc

select * from `collaboratori_utenti` where `collaboratori_utenti`.`id_utente` in (718, 834, 844, 848, 875, 890, 894, 895, 897, 898)

select * from `collaboratori` where `collaboratori`.`id` in (12,13,16)

select `collaboratori`.*, `collaboratori_utenti`.`id_utente` as `pivot_id_utente`, `collaboratori_utenti`.`collaboratori_id` as `pivot_collaboratori_id`, 
`collaboratori_utenti`.`attivita` as `pivot_attivita`, `collaboratori_utenti`.`created_at` as `pivot_created_at`, `collaboratori_utenti`.`updated_at` as `pivot_updated_at` 
from `collaboratori` inner join `collaboratori_utenti` on `collaboratori`.`id` = `collaboratori_utenti`.`collaboratori_id` 
where `collaboratori_utenti`.`id_utente` in (718, 834, 844, 848, 875, 890, 894, 895, 897, 898)
```

The first of those query is the slow one that causes a long time to wait.

Is there a way to change the EXIST with a faster query?

Comment: I think it will be more efficient with a join...

Comment: try changing ` 'like', $id_utente` to ` '=', $id_utente`

Comment: Why are you using like instead of =?

Comment: Using like will avoid mysql using indexes. Also, do you have a index on your colaboratori_id? Buona sera!

Comment: How much rows there are in each table?

Answer (score 1):

Only select fields you need. This will reduce the loading time.

Comment: wont affect query speed that much.

Answer (score 1):

In order to optimize the query time, you can use [laravel cursors](https://laravel.com/docs/6.x/eloquent#chunking-results). Instead of end your query with `->get()`, just use `->cursor()`, like this:

```
$utente = Utente::with('coll')->with('collaboratori')
    ->where('id', '<>', '0')
    ->whereHas('coll', function ($query) use($id_utente, $att_dummy){
        $query->where('collaboratori_id', 'like', $id_utente);})
    ->orderBy('created_at')
    ->cursor();
```

When working with big databases, it's better to use `cursor`. Here is a comparison of using get, chunk and cursor, [from this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/53736557/6184150):

> 10,000 records:
>
> ```
> +-------------+-----------+------------+
> |             | Time(sec) | Memory(MB) |
> +-------------+-----------+------------+
> | get()       |      0.17 |         22 |
> | chunk(100)  |      0.38 |         10 |
> | chunk(1000) |      0.17 |         12 |
> | cursor()    |      0.16 |         14 |
> +-------------+-----------+------------+
> ```
>
> 100,000 records:
>
> ```
> +--------------+------------+------------+
> |              | Time(sec)  | Memory(MB) |
> +--------------+------------+------------+
> | get()        |        0.8 |     132    |
> | chunk(100)   |       19.9 |      10    |
> | chunk(1000)  |        2.3 |      12    |
> | chunk(10000) |        1.1 |      34    |
> | cursor()     |        0.5 |      45    |
> +--------------+------------+------------+
> ```