# Difference between Laravel's lazy() vs cursor() method

Tags: php, laravel

## Things I couldn't understand:

1. What does it mean, especially the term 'flattened' and the 'result as single stream'.

> However, instead of passing each chunk directly into a callback as is, the lazy method returns a flattened LazyCollection of Eloquent models, which lets you interact with the results as a single stream

2. Why the `cursor()` method doesn't support eager loading? but the `lazy()` method can do that, how? as both returns the LazyCollection object.
3. What are the differences between both of these methods and when should we use them? How do their functionality differ internally?

## Things I understood:

1. The `lazy()` method executes query in chunks and the default chunk size for it is 1000.
2. The `cursor()` method doesn't use chunking but only execute a single database query.
3. Laravel's LazyCollection uses PHP generators internally. Therefore, only one Eloquent model is kept in memory at any given time while iterating over the cursor.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [What is the difference between laravel cursor and laravel chunk method?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45464676/what-is-the-difference-between-laravel-cursor-and-laravel-chunk-method)

Comment: no it doesn't i know that how chunk method works but why use lazy over cursor i want to know it

Comment: The way eager loading works is: (1) run the query for the parent model (2) run the query on the related model where the relationship ID matches any of the retrieved parent models. When using chunking you retrieve the chunk of the results so you are then able to eager load related models. When you using a cursor you only run a single query and "stream" the result so you can't see all the parent model IDs until you've streamed the entire result (which would defeat the purpose of using the cursor if you wanted to do that just for eager loading).

Answer (score 0):

To answer your 3rd question:

> What are the differences between both of these methods and when should we use them? How do their functionality differ internally?

I found this post very helpful: https://janostlund.com/2021-12-26/eloquent-cursor-vs-chunk

To answer your question more directly, the main difference between the lazy and cursor methods is that "An important advantage of cursor() is its consistency in processing datasets that might be subject to change during the processing period." (from the article linked above)

So if there is a chance that the dataset you're pulling could change while your code is executing, you'll want to use the cursor method. If that's not a concern, then using lazy() will probably be faster and more efficient.

To answer your other questions:

> 1. Why the cursor() method doesn't support eager loading? but the lazy() method can do that, how? as both returns the LazyCollection object.

I'm not too sure about that, sorry

> 2. What are the differences between both of these methods and when should we use them? How do their functionality differ internally?

My understanding is that neither support eager loading, but maybe that has changed?